# Tag 'form-1099-ent'

Tags: discussion, tags

What is [form-1099-ent](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-ent)? From the context it sounds like it should be [form-1099-nec](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-nec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [form-1099-ent](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-ent) tag and the two questions ([1](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/135537/10997), [2](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/135767/10997)) it is used in appear to entirely be the work of one user.

I agree, it appears to be actually referring to [Form 1099-NEC](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1099-nec).  This form was new in 2020*.  Before that, its function was combined with Form 1099-MISC.

We already have lots of questions tagged [form-1099-misc](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-misc), and almost all of them apply to the new 1099-NEC form.  The two forms are related, and [even share one set of instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1099msc).  I think my recommendation is to make [form-1099-nec](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-nec) a synonym of [form-1099-misc](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-misc) (or the other way around), edit the tag descriptions to make it clear that the tags apply to both, and get rid of this new [form-1099-ent](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-ent) tag, which [seems to be erroneous](https://www.irs.gov/site-index-search?search=1099-ent&field_pup_historical_1=1&field_pup_historical=1).

I have removed the [form-1099-ent](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-ent) tag from the two questions, and tagged them with [form-1099-misc](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-misc).  I have held off creating a new [form-1099-nec](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-nec) tag until we can come to consensus here how we want to handle it.  I have [asked a new meta question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3003/10997) to discuss how best to handle these tags.

---

<sub>* Actually, [it existed in 1979-1982](https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html?value=1099-NEC&criteria=formNumber&submitSearch=Find), and was brought back in 2020.</sub>