# What should we do about the Form 1099 tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

As I discussed in [an answer to another meta question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2988/10997), Form 1099-NEC was new in 2020*, and before that, its function was combined with Form 1099-MISC.

We already have lots of questions tagged [form-1099-misc](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-misc), and almost all of them apply to the new 1099-NEC form.  The two forms are related, and [even share one set of instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1099msc).

A couple of times now, users have (understandably) created a new [form-1099-nec](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-nec) tag.

How do we want to handle this?  Should we pick one tag and use it for all old and new questions?  Should we use two separate tags for the two differently-named forms, even though they are related?  If we do use one tag, should the other tag be created as a synonym tag?

---

<sub>* Actually, [it existed in 1979-1982](https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html?value=1099-NEC&criteria=formNumber&submitSearch=Find), and was brought back in 2020.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Because of all the historical questions we have about the 1099-MISC that also apply to today's 1099-NEC, my recommendation is to use the tag [form-1099-misc](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-misc), but edit the tag description to make it clear that it applies to both the 1099-MISC and the 1099-NEC.  We should also set up the tag [form-1099-nec](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-nec) as a synonym tag for the [form-1099-misc](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-misc) tag, so that askers and editors can type either one when searching or tagging.